# How do I see an event in different time zones in Google Calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I have an event in my Google Calendar. I'm using the web version and the app on my Android phone. It has a start time and an end time in my time zone.

I would like to see this event in different time zones. For example, I would like to see what the start and end times are in Europe/London and in Asia/Tokyo. Is there a way to easily do this from the Google Calendar interface?

Answer (score 1):

In *Google Calendar* » *Settings* there is an option to add an additional timezone to event views. Check *"Display secondary timezone"* and choose the timezone you would like to have displayed for events. This is available through the desktop app settings, and should take effect for all events.

To clarify, this will not be displayed within the event itself, but rather in the left-hand column in the *Day* or *Week* view. I am not aware of a builtin way of achieving an event-specific multiple timezone view.

Comment: The trouble with this is that I would like to display many time zones, not just one or two.

Comment: I see, unfortunately I'm unaware of a builtin way to achieve this. Theoretically this might be possible using a third-party browser extension, but I couldn't find anything that does this.